# Twilio statusCallback doesn't seem to be working as expected

Tags: php, callback, twilio

I have this to compose my recordings

```
$composition = $twilio->video->compositions->create($room_sid, [
            'audioSources' => $candidateParticipant->participant_sid,
            'videoLayout' =>  array(
                'single' => array (
                    'video_sources' => array($candidateParticipant->participant_sid)
                )
            ),
            'resolution' => '1280x720',
            'statusCallback' => 'https://mydevelopmentdomain.com/api/test',
            'format' => 'mp4'
        ]);
```

As you can see I have the statusCallback parameters inside but it doesn't seem to fire to the url. And also when I check the composition object, there's no "statusCallback" inside it

```
"accountSid" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
"status" => "completed"
"dateCreated" => DateTime @1586260399 {#980 ▶}
"dateCompleted" => DateTime @1586260421 {#981 ▶}
"dateDeleted" => null
"sid" => "CJ615c1e0e8318b7a88f0dc53ad410ae11"
"roomSid" => "RMacd06c604d9e9a8453dbb701d375b0f1"
"audioSources" => array:1 [▶]
"audioSourcesExcluded" => []
"videoLayout" => array:1 [▶]
"resolution" => "1280x720"
"trim" => true
"format" => "mp4"
"bitrate" => 1167
"size" => 3837839
"duration" => 26
"url" => "https://video.twilio.com/v1/Compositions/CJ615c1e0e8318b7a88f0dc53ad410ae11"
"links" => array:1 [▶]`enter code here`
```

Comment: FWIW, the example that Twilio gives doesn't show the callback URL in the JSON response either.  So that's probably not proof of a problem.  What have you done to confirm that the URL is not being called?  Have you checked your server access logs?

Comment: @PatrickQ it seems like I need to POST request. Because once I did that, it's starting to fire the url coming from statusCallback

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it works when I changed from GET request to POST request at the API route.

```
Route::post('/test',function (Request $request){
$cp_id = $request->get('cp_id');
$obj = \App\CandidateParticipant::find($cp_id);
$twilio = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($this->sid, $this->token);

$uri = "https://video.twilio.com/v1/Compositions/$obj->composition_sid/Media?Ttl=3600";
$response = $twilio->request("GET", $uri);

$mediaLocation = $response->getContent()["redirect_to"];


$path = 'proctoring/candidate_session-'.$obj->candidate_session_id.'/'.$obj->composition_sid.'.mkv';
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->put($path, file_get_contents($mediaLocation));

$obj->s3_path = $path;
$obj->save();
return 'done';

})
```